# I Need to code a Userform and apply a few different If Statement to create a cell value in a database

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula, userform

I am a student and new to VBA coding and programing. I need to create a code that will asses 3 if statement and based on the criteria of the if statements a cell value (discount given) will populate in the database we are working with. I have already created the userform to input a customer ID, customer name, sales value and DOB. The issue I am having is that I need to create an If statement based on the following:

1) If the customer was born earlier than 1/5/1960, their discount should be 10% of the sales value (only numbers should show up in the discount given column - not text)

2) If the customer was born after 1/20/1980, their discount should be 5% of the 
sales value (only numbers should show up in the discount given column - not text)

3) For all other customers, born on a different date, their discount should be 2% (so > 1/5/1960 and < 1/20/1980), (only numbers should show up in the discount given column - not text).

I inserted the code I wrote below, but it doesn't seem to be working I am hoping someone can help me.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

discount = Range("F8").Value

Rows(8).Insert Copyorigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

Range("B8").Value = TextBox1.Text
Range("C8").Value = TextBox2.Text
Range("D8").Value = TextBox3.Text
Range("E8").Value = TextBox4.Text
Range("F8").Value = discount

If discount < 1 / 5 / 1960 Then result = Range("D8").Value * 0.1 Else

If discount > 1 / 20 / 1980 Then result = Range("D8").Value * 0.05 Else

If discount > 1 / 5 / 1960 & discount < 1 / 20 / 1980 Then result = 
Range("D8").Value * 0.02

End If
End If
End If

Unload Me

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: what part of your code isn't working? what is it doing instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be better off using `SELECT CASE` instead of multiple `IF` statements.  It would also helped if you defined your variables.  Try something like this:

```
Dim dteDoB As Date

dteDoB = DateValue(Range("F8").Value)

Select Case dteDoB
    Case Is < DateValue("5/1/1960"): result = Range("D8").Value * 0.1
    Case Is > DateValue("20/1/1980"): result = Range("D8").Value * 0.05
    Case Else: esult = Range("D8").Value * 0.02
End Select
```

Comment: Hello my professor ended up responding to me w/ this: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Customers").Select
Range("B8").Select
Rows(8).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow = 1
Range("B8") = TextBox1.Text
Range("C8") = TextBox2.Text
Range("D8") = TextBox3.Text
Range("E8") = TextBox4.Text
If Range("E8") < #1/5/1960# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.1
Else
If Range("E8") > #1/20/1980# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.05
Else
If Range("E8") > #1/5/1960# Or Range("E8") < #1/20/1980# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.02
End If
End If
End If
Unload Me

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Test()

    Dim DateStart As Date, Result As Double

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        DateStart = Format(.Range("F8").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

        If DateStart < Format("1/5/1960", "dd/mm/yyyy") Then
            Result = .Range("D8").Value * 0.1
        ElseIf DateStart > Format("1/20/1980", "dd/mm/yyyy") Then
            Result = .Range("D8").Value * 0.05
        Else: Result = .Range("D8").Value * 0.02
        End If

    End With

 End Sub
```

Comment: 'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Customers").Select
Range("B8").Select
Rows(8).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow = 1

Range("B8") = TextBox1.Text
Range("C8") = TextBox2.Text
Range("D8") = TextBox3.Text
Range("E8") = TextBox4.Text

If Range("E8") < #1/5/1960# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.1

Else

If Range("E8") > #1/20/1980# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.05

Else
If Range("E8") > #1/5/1960# Or Range("E8") < #1/20/1980# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.02

End If
End If
End If

Unload Me


End Sub'

Comment: @bake3317 - it might be many things but I would not call it "correct code"

Answer (score 0):

Hello Thanks for the responses, my professor helped me out by pointing out that you can refer to a date using the # symbol. The correct code is as follows:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Sheets("Customers").Select
Range("B8").Select
Rows(8).Insert CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow = 1

Range("B8") = TextBox1.Text
Range("C8") = TextBox2.Text
Range("D8") = TextBox3.Text
Range("E8") = TextBox4.Text

If Range("E8") < #1/5/1960# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.1

Else

If Range("E8") > #1/20/1980# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.05

Else
If Range("E8") > #1/5/1960# Or Range("E8") < #1/20/1980# Then
Range("F8") = Range("D8") * 0.02

End If
End If
End If

Unload Me


End Sub
```